# Do we have liberty or limitation to answer in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, answers

Today I got into a situation while answering a question on Stack Overflow and choose to answer with all the etiquette I know. Simultaneously I got a comment on my answer saying "it's the same answer", while there was a key difference in my answer.

Let's say it was a case of synonyms. However, there the other answer was very different except that it's a kind of synonym keyword.

The other answer choose  "to answer" (`Index.notnull`), and I've chosen  "to reply" (`Index.notna`).

In reality, it was related to the Python pandas library.

Don't we have the freedom to put our answers unless it's exactly the same as another answer or copycatting?

Comment: You have the freedom to post any answer you want, but everyone else has the freedom to downvote your answer if they want.

Comment: @pizzastaticvoidmain, that's true but i want to understand the meaning saying same while i see that guys using similar keywords while answering on other post then not like same that's what i want to know the difference saying same. However, downvote  Even SO askes to comment to clarify before downvote.

Comment: If your answer is very similar, people still sometimes consider it a duplicate answer. People are encouraged to comment when they downvote, and it sounds like they did.

Comment: No, duplicate comes when the POST which is  there has answers already before. but we both are the ones who are answering for a question.

Comment: A duplicate answer is an answer that is the same *or very, very similar* to another answer on the same question. It sounds like your answer was similar enough to be considered a duplicate.

Comment: here is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54422869/how-to-extract-specified-row-from-excel-without-nan?noredirect=1#comment95657580_54422869) , i removed my answer  was `df[df.index.notna()]`

Comment: That smells like a chameleon question, to me.  Note the shifting requirements in the answer comments.

Comment: @pizzastaticvoidmain, yes, i have given my answer here.

Comment: @fbueckert, its really been chameleon.

Comment: any comparison so far :-) i'm okay with downvotes those will also make me understand.

Comment: Well, like I asked before, is this question specifically for how Stack Overflow deals with duplicate answers?  Or is it supposed to be more general for how the whole Stack Exchange network handles it?

Comment: in general  it should be applied to whole Stack n/w.

Answer (score 4):

In general, it depends on the site.  Each one will handle it differently.  For instance, my home site of Arqade's policy is to:

1. Downvote an answer that doesn't add anything new. (New is interpreted fairly broadly)
2. If over 20k, vote to delete.  Add a comment that says there's nothing new if not.
3. Once enough downvotes accumulate, the Low Quality queue can use Recommend Deletion, and not need moderator intervention.

From what I can find on M.SO, [the process looks somewhat similar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342211/should-we-be-allowed-to-flag-duplicate-answers).  I'm not that familiar with most sites, so I'm not sure how others would handle them.